# ReactJS event-driven updates on parent component

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, reactjs

I have some components that are buried deep inside their parents. I have a user variable, which is fetched at the absolute top of this chain (a `ProfilePage` component), and passed all the way down with props. But, sometimes the user updates its profile in a small component on the page (the `AboutMe` component for example). My current flow is to have the `AboutMe` component update the user via ajax, and then trigger an event called 'profileupdate' on my pubsub. When 'profileupdate' is triggered, the `ProfilePage` fetches the user again via ajax, and so all the props are updated. This tactic appears to work, but it almost always gives:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.
```

I know this error is coming from the ProfilePage not being mounted and replacing its user state.

Here is an example of a place where I do this:

In the `ProfilePage` component:

```
var ProfilePage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },

  updateUser: function() {
    this.setUser('/api/users/' + this.props.params.userId);
  },

  setCurrentUser: function(currentUser) {
    this.setState({ currentUser: currentUser });
  },

  resetCurrentUser: function() {
    auth.getCurrentUser.call(this, this.setCurrentUser);
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
    this.setUser('/api/users/' + newProps.params.userId);
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    PubSub.subscribe('profileupdate', this.updateUser);
    PubSub.subscribe('profileupdate', this.resetCurrentUser);
    this.resetCurrentUser();
    this.updateUser();
  },

  setUser: function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(user) {
        if (this.isMounted()) {
          this.setState({ user: user });
        } else {
          console.log("ProfilePage not mounted.");
        }  
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.userId, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Then, in the AboutInput component:
ProfilePage --> ProfileBox --> About --> AboutInput

```
updateAbout: function(text) {
  var url = '/api/users/' + this.props.user._id;
  var user = this.props.user;
  user.about = text;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: user,
    success: function(user) {
      auth.storeCurrentUser(user, function(user) {
        return user;
      });
      PubSub.publish('profileupdate');
      this.propagateReset();
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(status, err.toString());
      this.propagateReset();
    }.bind(this)
  });
},
```

The takeaways here are that the ProfilePage fetches the user again when the profileupdate event is triggered.

Am I using the wrong tactics here? How can I handle this kind of update? And, can I force the ProfilePage to become mounted? That would be really ideal. Also, interestingly, whether or not the console logs that the ProfilePage is unmounted, the user still updates.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of code that causes the invariant violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really would take a look at Facebook's FLUX implementation. It will simplify your workflow tremendously. I am guessing that is not an option at this moment, but make sure your components are unsubscribing when removing them. For eg:

```
componentWillUnmount: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.store.removeListener('change', self._setState);
    self._setState = null;
}
```

Or in your case unsubscribe using the method above from your PubSub implementation when a component is being replaced. So 'profileupdate' is being called on a React component that has been unmounted. Something like.

```
componentWillUnmount: function () {
    PubSub.unsubscribe('profileupdate', this.updateUser);
    PubSub.unsubscribe('profileupdate', this.resetCurrentUser);
    this.updateUser = null;
    this.resetCurrentUser = null;
}
```

It is exactly what the error states. You trying to set state on a React component that is not longer mounted, or has been removed.

Comment: Hm, I'll take a look at the flux implementation. Won't this solution mean that the props will not get updated? When will the ProfilePage re-mount and update?

Comment: This should be on all components that have events bound to them. You should always unbound events to any component that will be mounted and unmounted. If not, you will encounter memory leaks and all sorts of strange errors will occur. In your code snippet above you are not showing how your are implementing ProfileBox --> About --> AboutInput. I.e are you passing props or state and how are these components being updated?

Comment: The user is a state retrieved by the ProfilePage. This user is passed down as props through many layers of components, eventually reaching the AboutInput. So, if I unsubscribe from the event in the ProfilePage, then the AboutInput triggers the event, and then the ProfilePage remounts (and consequently resubscribes to the event), does that mean it will still update?